# Is it possible to write IF conditions inside Lodash templates (_.template)?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Something like:

```
<div>
    <%- if (condition) { %>
        <div>This text will be shown if `condition` is true</div>
    <%- } %>
</div>
```

The above example is not working so i'm asking if there is any way to use IF conditions inside the template string, I know that Underscore support it out of the box.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this:

```
<% if (condition) { %>...<% } %>
```

(in other words: remove the hyphen)